Find and replace using wildcards in Microsoft Word 365 desktop not working
I previously had a Word document using wild cards. I would use a Find and Replace using "&" as my delimiter and "*" as my Wildcard. When I had a phrase such as the following:
&On average, how many hours of sleep are you getting each night?&
On average, the patient reports getting Click or tap here to enter text. hours of sleep a night.
the text between the &'s disappeared and what was left was:
On average, the patient reports getting Click or tap here to enter text. hours of sleep a night.
However, when I add another sentence beneath also delimited as follows:
&On average, how many hours of sleep are you getting each night?&
On average, the patient reports getting Click or tap here to enter text. hours of sleep a night.   &[He/She/They] indicated, “Click or tap here to enter text.” &
When I run the Find and Replace again, the second sentence with &'s does not disappear:
On average, the patient reports getting Click or tap here to enter text. hours of sleep a night.
&[He/She/They] indicated, “Click or tap here to enter text.” &
Bizarrely, sometimes the second delimited sentence does disappear when it looks identical to the one above, for instance:
&Have you ever been diagnosed with ADD or ADHD?&
The patient Choose an item. been diagnosed with ADD or ADHD.  &[He/She/They] was diagnosed at age Click or tap here to enter text.  [He/She/They] reported, “Click or tap here to enter text.” &
I tried using a second delimiter such as "%" and "$".  It does not show above but the "&" are highlighted. The first in purple and the second in red. I tried removing the highlighting but this did not fix the proble.
